# Plugin to translate web app news feeds etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2008

Our web application makes it possible for registered users to subscribe to news feeds and forums. They can then post there, but the problem comes in users are from different cultures thus post in different languages. What plugins if any are there available that i can implement to allow users to be able to translate to their language so they can read all of the news posts and forum posts?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in 2012 ? Tanslation is a very hard subject... automatic translation is even harder !

Comment: I think your best bet - is Google Translate, which is supported out of the box in Chrome. Automatic translation is an unsolved computing problem of tremendous complexity, so brightests minds of IT industry haven't comed with robust solution yet. So, I mean, most likely there would be no such plugin, standalone application, service or anything, that can translate between native languages in a decade or so.

Comment: maybe i should not translate but have users in the same country/same language just see their own? but then you might miss out on important discussions/news.